# how can I pass facebook AccessToken object by Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, facebook-access-token

I am trying to pass facebook's AccessToken object to another activity via Intent.putExtra.

```
intent.putExtra("ACCESS_TOKEN", loginResult.getAccessToken());
```

and trying to get it on second activiy as

```
AccessToken fbAccessToken = (AccessToken)intent.getSerializableExtra("ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY");
```

It says that it cannot be casted from Serializable to AccessToken because it is not serializable object.

What I think is to create serializable wrapper class which includes AccessToken field and pass it by intent. Is it good way to do that or what could be better way to pass it?

Comment: why do you want to pass all the AccessToken object?

Comment: I want to keep further works in another activity.

Comment: with accesstoken object or the accesstoken string?

Comment: with accesstoken object itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are logged in then in the next activity you can get the currentAccessToken like this:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(accessToken==null || accessToken.isExpired()){
    // maybe login again
}
```

do not forget to add FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); in the activity before setContentView() method

Comment: thank you very much Panayiotis. It is exactly what I was looking for.